# sqlalchemy : Column must be constructed with a non-blank name

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

I try to insert new records into a table on amazon redshift .
Basically i download rows from a google spreadsheet and  try to push as a Dataframe into a table.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://redshift_user:password,GB8@redshift-url:5439/datawarehouse')
connection = engine.raw_connection()
```

and then i excute

```
df.to_sql(name='test',con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

but it dosen't work and it raises the exception

`sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Column must be constructed with a non-blank name or assign a non-blank .name before adding to a Table.`

i checked some posts and tried their solutions but still not working

Comment: maybe try making a Table class that inherits SQLAlchemy.Module? I'm just a beginner with SQLAlchemy though.

Comment: hmm , do you have an example for that ? i'am also a newbie with SQLAlchemy

Comment: I mostly use flask-sqlalchemy

Comment: Any chance that the `df` dataframe has unnamed columns (or multi-level column names)? You can see that by `print(df.columns)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import SQLAlchemy sqla

db_uri = ''
db = sqla.create_engine('postgresql://file.db')


class Table(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'USER[{self.id}, {self.name]'
db.create_all()
user1 = Table(username='User1')
db.session.add(user1)
db.session.commit()
```

WARNING YOU WILL HAVE TO DEBUG THIS... I only worked with Flask + SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 0):

thx for the help.

Turn out that i had an empty column in my dataframe that i didn't notice in the beginning that caused the error .
Once i fixed the import from google sheets , the parsing to the database also worked